# read_sql_query returns far more records than actual table rows

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

I am trying to get the a postgresql table in to python data frame. But the dataframe size is extremely larger than the actual number of table records even though I specified an index column. What's causing this issue? Single quotes/ commas in the database table?

```
import psycopg2 as pg
import pandas.io.sql as psql


connection = pg.connect("dbname=BeaconDB user=admin password=root")
dataframe = psql.read_sql_query(sql="SELECT * from encounters2", con=connection, index_col='encounter_id')
print('size::::', dataframe.size)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[df.size](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) shows you the number of elements (cells) in the DF

Demo:

```
In [134]: df
Out[134]:
   A   B
0  3  11
1  0   2

In [135]: df.size
Out[135]: 4

In [136]: df.shape
Out[136]: (2, 2)

In [137]: len(df)
Out[137]: 2

In [138]: len(df.index)
Out[138]: 2
```